# AHK Run commands every time a window becomes active

Tags: autohotkey

I want the NO Button to be pressed when the below window opens, it opens repeatedly and a few after each other.

[image: Window that opens]

My current method is to run a timer loop which image searches for the window and then controlclicks the button when the image is found.

```
SetTimer(Timer, 500)

Timer(){
    if ImageSearch(&OutputVarX, &OutputVarY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, "Image.png") {
        ControlClick("Button3", "Information")
    }
}
```

This however is slow because as i said the window apears severa times in busts so i need something that can click the moment the window opens.

Comment: You can use Window Spy, which is installed alongside AHK, taking note of that information window's `ahk_class` or `ahk_exe` (just point your cursor to that window when it's active). If it's unique, you can use [WinExist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinExist.htm) alongside a Timer.

Comment: Is the value there unique and consistent to that specific window? I'm afraid another "Information" Window appears and then it clicks "no" before I have time to react, and also, if I run a 50 ms timer with the winexist in, will it slow my PC?

Comment: I can't say for sure. Try using Window Spy. If your script is solely dedicated to clicking the "no" button, you can use [WinWaitActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinWaitActive.htm) inside a `while` loop, which performs better. The main downside is that it "freezes" your script, see the Remarks section of the WinWaitActive link.